# монтирование к linux зашифрованного home

Tags: linux, ubuntu, установка

Имеется Ubuntu где система на одном логическом диске, а home на другом. Home зашифрован, хочу переустановить систему и подключить старый home. То есть если я установлю заново систему на тот диск, где она была ранее, при установке создам пользователя с тем же именем и паролем, что были ранее и при установке укажу старый home. Не будет при таком варианте проблем, что home зашифрован и он не подключится к новой системе?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/q/1076462/416190

Answer (score 0):

Да. При установке с вашими параметрами скорее всего перезапишится каталог /home.  Если надо восстановить какие то  файлы есть скрипт для восстановления :  [Тема: Доступ к файлам после переустановки системы](https://forum.ubuntu.ru/index.php?topic=105108.msg791922#msg791922)

Также попробуйте при установке не изменять раздел /home и примонтировать его уже после установки системы.... Далее смотрите инфу по ссылке выше...